# Right shift operator on mac safari not working

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code and used >> (right shift operator) , the ui is totally messed up.I debugged and found that its doing wrong math and finally found right shift operator is not working mac safari.

Is this a known behavior or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Is it working on other browsers/other operating systems?

Comment: yeah , IE and firefox works fine , even chrome. I changed code to divide/2

Comment: Mmh works on the console... `4 >> 1` gives `2`... sure that it is not something else? I cannot imagine that Apple implemented bit operators wrongly...

Comment: Would you like to share the section of your code that is creating the error in Safari?

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you using right shift in the first place? Since javascript only has a single type for numbers, doing binary operations on them can be dangerous and provide unexpected results.

Comment: it was old code , somebody did it , while debugging i found this problem on safari and changed the code for safer side and it was urgent.

Comment: top = ((containerHeight - maxH) >> 1) + topOffset;    
    left = (containerWidth - maxW) >> 1; this code is failing on safari

Comment: What results *do* you get? As Felix Kling said, "works on the console". I'd be more inclined to believe another value is incorrect. You can test this by changing `x >> 1` to (roughly) `parseInt(x / 2)`. Make sure that `x` isn't undefined or something else wonk.

Comment: I don't have safari on my machine, i have to goto another place to verify it , is there any way we can simulate safar on windows server.

Comment: @gov have you tried installing Safari for Windows? And I very, very strongly suspect that the >> operator itself is working fine. Maybe some of the stuff that generates the left- and right-side *operands* to the >> operator are misbehaving.

Comment: Ok , i got clarified on this part. I will debug after i install safari for windows. Thanks for all the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fill with zeros with `>>>` when you have big numbers

```
>>> 2147483648>>2
-536870912
>>> 2147483648>>>2
536870912
```